# How to match all lines between the last two strings pasterns in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have log file with some repeating keywords like 'Start' and 'End', with several lines in between (including spaces). I want to grep all the lines between those two tags --but only for the very last recursion. For example:

```
Start 
1

2 
End 
Start 
A B 
C 
Start 
Three 
End
```

The result should only be "Three"

Comment: I'd rather do this in `sed` or `awk`.  Would that be acceptable?

Comment: Yes, either `sed` or `awk` would qualify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk '/Start/{s=""; p=1; next} p && /End/{p=0} p{s=s $0 ORS} END{printf "%s", s}' file
Three
```

Or using `tac` and `awk`:

```
tac file | awk '/End/{p=1; next} p && /Start/{exit} p' | tac
Three
```

Comment: You need to `tac` the result too in case there are more than one line